# Where is Chocobo's Dungeon for PlayStation?

Tags: final-fantasy-series

I'm trying to find out more information about *Chocobo's Dungeon*. Apparently there's a [*Chocobo's Dungeon 2*](http://asia.gamespot.com/chocobos-dungeon-2/) for PSX but [*Chocobo's Dungeon*](http://asia.gamespot.com/final-fantasy-fables-chocobos-dungeon/) (1?) is for Wii.

Where is *Chocobo's Dungeon* 1 for PSX? Why the sudden jump to 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Predecessor to Chocobo's Dungeon 2 is called [Chocobo's Mysterious Dungeon (Chocobo no Fushigina Dungeon)](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Chocobo_no_Fushigi_na_Dungeon)
for the PSX.

You might read about it in the link above.
It was primarily released for Japan and probably did not get a translation till much later.

Comment: So that means I won't be able to find an english version of it then?

Comment: @ShedoSurashu That is correct. the first game was never released in English.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the confirmation @Krazer. Too bad, I wanted to try it out first before playing Chocobo's Dungeon 2.